# Reading and writing tables from a list of labels in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

How can I create a file containing a table created from a list of labels, E.g. if I had two labels above and below each other like this

`foo
bar`

They would be written into a table like this

Number Name

1----------foo

2----------bar

That table would then need to be written to a file.

Also how can I read the table from the file and create a list of labels on a panel.

Comment: Can't you make use of a GridView?

Comment: there is a csv helper which can write and read csv files. you just have to define a class with Number and Name Property. https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write records into lines in a file.

```
var rows = panel.Controls.OfType<Label>().Select(t => t.Text);

File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", rows);
```

And read it line by line.

```
var rows = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt');

for (var i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
{
    var label = new Label
    {
        Text = rows[i],
        Top = i * 30
    };
    panel.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: How can I create a label for each line?

Comment: Directly create labels and add to your panel. Of course, I would suggest using FlowLayout or TableLayoutPanel instead of a general Panel.

Comment: 'Panel' Does not contain a definition for 'Add'.

Comment: Oh, it's panel.Controls.Add

Comment: Finally, how can I detect which label was clicked and put the label text into a variable and execute a method?

Comment: Microsoft has detailed WinForm tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd492131.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116503/discussion-between-tommy-and-towtow10).